# VSTS NuGet pack exclude test projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I am using VSTS vNext build system to build a C# solution.
Below you can see the settings for the NuGet Packager. The path to nuspec files is set to reference the .csproj files.

[image]

However this includes all .csproj files; I need to **exclude** test projects. Ignoring 'Core.Test.csproj' but still packaging 'Core.csproj'.

I have tried '***.csproj;-:!***test.csproj' and other combinations but have had no luck figuring this out! Does anyone know how the pattern matching works for vNext build?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`**\*.csproj;-:**\*test.csproj` should do it (no exclaimation point needed). If not, we may have a bug, and you should file it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks).

Comment: Are you aware of being able to do more than one exclude?  e.g. `**/*.csproj;-:**/*.Tests.csproj;-:**/*.ConsoleApp.csproj`

Comment: I'm finding that it doesn't :s should I raise it as an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Yes. I'm not on that team anymore but I'll forward this to someone who is.

Comment: The exclude pattern has changed. From the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget#pack-nuget-packages): Use file matching patterns to publish multiple packages. Note that these patterns were updated in version 2 of the NuGet task; if you have a pattern that contains -:, use ! instead.

Answer (score 11):

The latest version (2.x) of the [NuGet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget?view=vsts) in VSTS and TFS 2018 uses a different pattern for excluding packages. Now you use `!` instead of `-:`.

So `**\*.csproj;-:**\*.Test.csproj` changes to `**\*.csproj;!**\*.Test.csproj`.

Full pattern matching documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=vsts).